# htmlentites certain string inside HTML tag

Tags: php

I have this string:

`$str = "<ul><li>Eüro!</li><li>100 %</li><li>Jäckö<br></li></ul>";`

I am planning to do use `htmlentities()` on the string inside those `<li></li>`. So it will come up like this:

`$str = "<ul><li>E&uuml;ro!</li><li>100 %</li><li>J&auml;ck&ouml;<br></li></ul>";`

Is there a way or workaround with `htmlentities()` to not convert the entire string? Because if I simply do `htmlentities($str)`, it will convert the entire string which will result into:

`&lt;ul&gt;&lt;li&gtE&uuml;ro!&lt;/li&gt;&lt;li&gt;100 %&lt;/li&gt;&lt;li&gt;J&auml;ck&ouml;&lt;br&gt;&lt;/li&gt;&lt;/ul&gt;`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can create your own replacement function:

```
function parseAccents($in) {
    $out=$in;
    $toreplace=array(
        array('ü', '&uuml;'),
        array('ä', '&auml;'),
        array('ö', '&ouml;')
        // ...  
    );
    for($i=0; $i<count($toreplace); $i++) $out=str_replace($toreplace[$i][0], $toreplace[$i][1], $out);
    return $out;
}
```

EDIT: In case you don't want to set the entire list of accents, you can use this model:

```
function parseAccents($in) {
    $out=htmlentities($in);
    $toreplace=array(
        array('&lt;', '<'),
        array('&gt;', '>'),
        // ...  
    );
    for($i=0; $i<count($toreplace); $i++) $out=str_replace($toreplace[$i][0], $toreplace[$i][1], $out);
    return $out;
}
```

Comment: But by that I have to know what characters will be inputted. I prefer `htmlentites` because I may not know what is in there.

Comment: Then you can use htmlentities, and back replace &lt; and &gt;

Comment: Be very careful with the "edit" here, as you have a high likelihood of introducing an XSS hole if any of the content inside the list is user-provided.

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/es/function.htmlentities.php), you can see you have some flags:

```
string htmlentities ( string $string [, int $flags = ENT_COMPAT | ENT_HTML401 [, string $encoding = 'UTF-8' [, bool $double_encode = true ]]] )
```

So you can see the output from some strings here:

```
<?php
  $str = "A 'quote' is <b>bold</b>";

  // Produces: A 'quote' is &lt;b&gt;bold&lt;/b&gt;
  echo htmlentities($str);

  // Produces: A &#039;quote&#039; is &lt;b&gt;bold&lt;/b&gt;
  echo htmlentities($str, ENT_QUOTES);
?>
```

I think this will depend on your default charcode, so you can maybe try different flags.

Comment: I don't have an issue with the quote.

Comment: The quote example is just an example of a flag usage. Anyway, I think you are using the wrong function. AFAIK, htmlentities() has a different purpose from replacing just some language-specific characters.

Answer (score 0):

Find a way to not pass that as a single string until you've htmlentities()-ed the subfunctions. Treat it as an array of list items, then call htmlentities on each of them as you build up the `<ul>` from it. Anything else means you've got a high chance of an XSS hole.

Answer (score 0):

```
$str = '<ul><li>Eüro!</li><li>100 %</li><li>Jäckö<br></li></ul>';


function update_li_content($text){        
    return "<li>".htmlentities($text[1])."</li>";
}

$reg = "#<li>(.*?)</li>#";

$filter_data =  preg_replace_callback ( $reg, "update_li_content", $str);

echo $filter_data;
```